# What is the best way to remove a table row with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

What is the best method for removing a table row with jQuery?

Answer (score 484, accepted):

You're right:

```
$('#myTableRow').remove();
```

This works fine if your row has an `id`, such as:

```
<tr id="myTableRow"><td>blah</td></tr>
```

If you don't have an `id`, you can use any of jQuery's [plethora of selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Comment: Doing it this way does mean you need one id per row which potentially adds a lot of overhead. jQuery allows other approaches which are more idiomatic (to jQuery's approach), carry on reading there are more suggestions.

Comment: For dynamic content make row id `unique` you can do it by appending something unique like this for php `<tr id="myTableRow<?php echo $id; ?>">` and same thing you have to generate this id when you remove it :)

Answer (score 141):

```
$('#myTable tr').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
});
```

Even a better one

```
$("#MyTable").on("click", "#DeleteButton", function() {
   $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 64):

Assuming you have a button/link inside of a data cell in your table, something like this would do the trick...

```
$(".delete").live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

This will remove the parent of the parent of the button/link that is clicked. You need to use parent() because it is a jQuery object, not a normal DOM object, and you need to use parent() twice, because the button lives inside a data cell, which lives inside a row....which is what you want to remove. $(this) is the button clicked, so simply having something like this will remove only the button:

```
$(this).remove();
```

While this will remove the data cell:

```
    $(this).parent().remove();
```

If you want to simply click anywhere on the row to remove it something like this would work. You could easily modify this to prompt the user or work only on a double-click:

```
$(".delete").live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: What if the link is not directly inside the td, but has, say, a span around it? I think it'd be better to do $(this).parents('tr').remove(); to let it walk up the DOM tree by itself, find the tr, and remove it.

Comment: That would work too. It all depends on where in the DOM your button/link is, which is why I gave so many examples and such a long explanation.

Comment: You can also use $(this).parents('tr')

Comment: .live was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9. See [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 46):

You can use:

```
$($(this).closest("tr"))
```

for finding the parent table row of an element.

It is more elegant than parent().parent() which is what I started out doing and soon learnt the error of my ways.

--Edit --
Someone pointed out that the question was about removing the row...

```
$($(this).closest("tr")).remove()
```

As pointed out below you can simply do:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

A similar code snippet can be used for many operations such as firing events on multiple elements.

Comment: A little more succinct: `$(this).closest("tr").remove()`

Answer (score 16):

Easy.. Try this

```
$("table td img.delete").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeTo(400, 0, function () { 
        $(this).remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I would change `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` to `$(this).closest('tr')`. It's more robust and clearly shows what you're selecting.

Answer (score 9):

Is the following acceptable:

```
$('#myTableRow').remove();
```

Comment: This removes the whole table, not just the rows for the table. It leaves nothing to append to if you just want to clear out the rows.

Answer (score 9):

All you have to do is to remove the table row (`<tr>`) tag from your table. For example here is the code to remove the last row from the table:

> `$('#myTable tr:last').remove();`

*Code above was taken from [**this jQuery Howto post**](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/remove-bottom-table-row-using-jquery.html).

Answer (score 8):

```
function removeRow(row) {
    $(row).remove();
}

<tr onmousedown="removeRow(this)"><td>Foo</td></tr>
```

Maybe something like this could work as well? I haven't tried doing something with "this", so I don't know if it works or not.

Comment: Well, I would say that would be a little weird have the row disappear when you click on it. At the moment I have a link in the row to delete the row.

Answer (score 8):

try this for size

```
$(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
```

full listing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.deleteRowButton').click(DeleteRow);
      });

    function DeleteRow()
    {
      $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr><td>foo</td>
     <td><a class="deleteRowButton">delete row</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>bar bar</td>
     <td><a class="deleteRowButton">delete row</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>bazmati</td>
     <td><a class="deleteRowButton">delete row</a></td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxa30tpp/)

Answer (score 3):

Another one by `empty()` :

```
$(this).closest('tr').empty();
```

Comment: Doesn't that remove all the <td>'s but not the <tr>? I'm guessing the browser may remove the <tr> automatically, but I suspect that's no guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

If the row you want to delete might change you can use this.  Just pass this function the row # you wish to delete.

```
function removeMyRow(docRowCount){
   $('table tr').eq(docRowCount).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have HTML like this

```
<tr>
 <td><span class="spanUser" userid="123"></span></td>
 <td><span class="spanUser" userid="123"></span></td>
</tr>
```

where `userid="123"` is a custom attribute that you can populate dynamically when you build the table,

you can use something like

```
  $(".spanUser").live("click", function () {

        var span = $(this);   
        var userid = $(this).attr('userid');

        var currentURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
        var url = currentURL + "/Account/DeleteUser/" + userid;

        $.post(url, function (data) {
          if (data) {
                   var tdTAG = span.parent(); // GET PARENT OF SPAN TAG
                   var trTAG = tdTAG.parent(); // GET PARENT OF TD TAG
                   trTAG.remove(); // DELETE TR TAG == DELETE AN ENTIRE TABLE ROW 
             } else {
                alert('Sorry, there is some error.');
            }
        }); 

     });
```

So in that case you don't know the class or id of the `TR` tag but anyway you are able to delete it.

Comment: think  live is now deprecated in favour of  on, $(".spanUser").on('click', function (){

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr').click(function()
 {
  $(this).remove();
 });
```

i think you will try the above code, as it work, but i don't know why it work for sometime and then the whole table is removed. i am also trying to remove the row by click the row. but could not find exact answer.

Comment: I am not sure if you already tried the $('tr').live("click",function(){ $(this).remove();});

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is an old post, but I was looking to do the same, and found the accepted answer didn't work for me. Assuming JQuery has moved on since this was written.

Anyhow, I found the following worked for me:

```
$('#resultstbl tr[id=nameoftr]').remove();
```

Not sure if this helps anyone. My example above was part of a larger function so not wrapped it in an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

id is not a good selector now. You can define some properties on the rows. And you can use them as selector.

```
<tr category="petshop" type="fish"><td>little fish</td></tr>
<tr category="petshop" type="dog"><td>little dog</td></tr>
<tr category="toys" type="lego"><td>lego starwars</td></tr>
```

and you can use a func to select the row like this (ES6):

```
const rowRemover = (category,type)=>{
   $(`tr[category=${category}][type=${type}]`).remove();
}

rowRemover('petshop','fish');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap Tables

add this code snippet to your bootstrap_table.js

```
BootstrapTable.prototype.removeRow = function (params) {
    if (!params.hasOwnProperty('index')) {
        return;
    }

    var len = this.options.data.length;

    if ((params.index > len) || (params.index < 0)){
        return;
    }

    this.options.data.splice(params.index, 1);

    if (len === this.options.data.length) {
        return;
    }

    this.initSearch();
    this.initPagination();
    this.initBody(true);
};
```

Then in your `var allowedMethods = [`

add `'removeRow'`

Finally you can use `$("#your-table").bootstrapTable('removeRow',{index:1});`

[Credits to this post](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/453)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to remove rows from table:

1. Remove row of table using its unique ID.
2. Remove based on the order/index of that row. Ex: remove the third or fifth row.

For example:

```
 <table id='myTable' border='1'>
    <tr id='tr1'><td>Row1</td></tr>
    <tr id='tr2'><td>Row2</td></tr>
    <tr id='tr3'><td>Row3</td></tr>
    <tr id='tr4'><td>Row4</td></tr>
    <tr id='tr5'><td>Row5</td></tr>
  </table>

//======REMOVE TABLE ROW=========
//1. remove spesific row using its ID
$('#tr1').remove();

//2. remove spesific row using its order or index.
//row index started from 0-n. Row1 index is 0, Row2 index is 1 and so on.
$('#myTable').find('tr:eq(2)').remove();//removing Row3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is undoubtedly the easiest way:

```
$("#your_tbody_tag").empty();
```