# How to use jquery or javascript to remove a row at index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to remove a table row with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170997/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-a-table-row-with-jquery)

If I have table with 3 rows using `tr` tag, how do I remove the first row (index 0) with either jquery or some other javascript?

Comment: +1 for asking for a non-jQuery approach.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of the stated question.  This asks specifically about removing by index and also asks about non-jQuery ways of doing this.

Answer (score 11):

try

```
$("tr").eq(0).remove();
```

However, like @Gregg said, take a look at [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 10):

This would remove the 3rd row in a table.

```
$("table tr:eq(2)").remove();
```

Also, don't forget to use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` in your `<table>`.  It makes things more accessible and helps if you want to use a plug-in for sorting later down the road.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the "some other javascript" approach, which is itself very simple:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
```

Comment: Of interest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableElement

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/) are a great resource for this kind of thing...

```
$("tr:first").remove()
```