# Delete row in a table by clicking cell in another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tables: one-column table standing next to the multi-column table. I want to delete a row in a multi-column table by clicking the cell in a one-column table that is standing next to this row.

I am trying to do this by using this code:

```
$('.my-table').on('click','td .del-row-td',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Where .my-table is a multi-column table and .del-row-td is a cell in a one-column table. Maybe "closest" does not work if these are two separate objects?

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/bgfvn8aw/) where I am trying to do this. And [here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3H1y.jpg) an explanation in the image.

Comment: You have a bunch of identical `id`'s like `del-column-td`. `id`'s have to be unique.

Comment: @Frecosos, thank you, I have corrected that but forget to save)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the index of the one-column tr and remove the matching multi-column tr

```
$('#table-del tr').click(function(){
  var trIndex = $("tr", $(this).closest("table")).index(this);
  $($('#my-table tr')[trIndex]).remove()
  $(this).remove();
})
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5k0qeoqL/1/) (updated to use `on`)

some nicer code options to delete the matching tr [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821719/how-to-use-jquery-or-javascript-to-remove-a-row-at-index)

Comment: thank you! It worked with the rows that were there in the beginning. But somehow it does not work for the rows that are added with the "+" button (yellow). Do you have any ideas why is that so? Here is the current version with your code in it: https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/bgfvn8aw/1/

Comment: yes, my bad, sorry, changed to use `on`, working version: https://jsfiddle.net/5k0qeoqL/1/

Comment: thank you again, I would not guess it! And I hope the last question :) : do you have any idea why "add" button stops adding rows if I delete the top row in the table? I can delete and add any quantity of rows and it works fine, but when I delete the top one - it stops adding rows...

Comment: since the element for adding columns is hiding it, you gave them all `position:absolute`, which i dont think is recommended, you'll need to find a css solution for that

Comment: thank you for noticing it! I will look for the solution.