# How to delete table rows of specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table with few rows. in that for few rows `someClass` is applied.

My request is how can i delete the rows of specific class type?

```
<table>
<tr class="someClass"> ...</tr>
<tr class="someClass"> ...</tr>
<tr class="anotherClass"> ...</tr>
<tr class="someClass"> ...</tr>
</table>
```

Now i have to delete all the rows whose class type is `someClass` using jquery. How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: `$('.someClass').remove();`

Comment: $('table tr.someClass').remove();

Comment: Honestly, did you Goog?

Comment: [Api jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) seems a good place to start.

Comment: literally the top result: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=How+to+delete+table+rows+of+specific+class

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove a table row with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170997/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-a-table-row-with-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('table tr.someClass').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('.someClass').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

How's this?:

`$(".someClass").remove();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.someClass').remove();
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

first you should indentify the event, and write the event handler then use the  shared code.sample event is on click something and perform the operation

```
$('.someClass').remove();//
```

TRY to GOOGLE, you will get a lots of samples.