# Remove only the tr on the tbody

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html which, of course, have a table element, and in the tbody, I have a button that will delete rows of the table.

I have assigned an `onclick=""` function to the button. [(Function here)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)

**How to delete only the rows on the body of the table (*tbody*), and not the row in the head of the table (*thead*) ?**

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/t18zutyx/)**

Comment: please post you code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove a table row with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170997/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-a-table-row-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap body rows to `tbody` element and than you can to select only `table tbody tr` to be removed. With jQuery you can do `$('table tbody tr').remove();`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some content</td>
      <td>
        <button onClick="$(this).closest('tr').remove()">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Some content</td>
      <td>
        <button onClick="$(this).closest('tr').remove()">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Some content</td>
      <td>
        <button onClick="$(this).closest('tr').remove()">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Some content</td>
      <td>
        <button onClick="$(this).closest('tr').remove()">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onClick="$('#table tbody tr').remove()">Remove all rows</button>
```